# UWP freezes when trying to register a background task with SocketActivityTrigger

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am trying to register a background task with SocketActivityTrigger on app launch using the following code (inside the OnLaunched method of the App class):

```
foreach (var t in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
{ t.Value.Unregister(true); }
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = exampleTaskName;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = "RuntimeComponent1.Class1";
builder.SetTrigger(new SocketActivityTrigger());
task = builder.Register();
```

As you see, at the beginning I am removing all previously registered tasks to make sure that I am not registering the task twice. The project of the background task (the Runtime Component project) is referenced from my App project, the background task is declared in declarations in the manifest and the internet and private network capabilites are also checked in the manifest.

When I run it for a couple of times, it works, and then it starts to freeze while starting and cannot start as you see in the screenshot:

[image]

After rebooting the PC, it starts to work again, and after many times it starts to freeze again, until I reboot again ... etc.

I already tried to use `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();` before registering but the problem is not solved.

The same happens even with this [app](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket) from Microsoft! It starts correctly the first times and then starts to freeze after launched like in the screenshot until I reboot:

[image]

The problem is only with `SocketActivityTrigger`; when I try to register a task with another trigger (such as SystemTrigger of type SystemTriggerType.TimeZoneChange) the problem does not occur.

Update: I noticed that the problem starts after a connection to the socket is made.

Comment: We tested the official sample on two computers, one computer acts as a server and the other registers with SocketActivityTrigger. When they connected successfully, and no matter how many times it re-runs, it worked well. So I can't reproduce this issue. What's your system version and target version number? And if you test this in another machine, will the same issue occur?

Comment: I am targeting Build 18362. I didn't try on another machine. It should be because of some mistake in my implementation of the background task because it starts to happen after a connection is made once to my app that triggers the SocketActivityTrigger. I will reform my question in a new question.

Comment: Here is it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59716347/using-streamsocketlistener-in-the-background-with-socketactivitytrigger

Comment: Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Here is one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hzxgeyt8vuulq7k/App1.zip

Comment: By testing your sample, I can't reproduce this issue. If you test this project in another machine, will the same issue occur?