# Using StreamSocketListener in the background with SocketActivityTrigger

Tags: c#, websocket, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In order to make a UWP App act like an HTTP server, [restup](https://github.com/tomkuijsten/restup) does the job. But the problem is that it does not provide an HTTP server that works even after the app is closed.

In order to achieve this, a background task with SocketActivityTrigger has to be created and the socket ownership of StreamSocketListener has to be transferred to the socket broker so that the background task is triggered when a request comes (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/network-communications-in-the-background)). And [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket) is an example for an app that connects to a socket and keeps receiving messages even after the app is closed.

I tried to adapt this to make restup work in the background as well, but in vain!

Could someone help on this please?

Comment: Can you explain exactly where you are having an issue?  There is a lot of code and no indication what you issue is.  If the http server is not working that a http header need to be added/modified.  The best way of getting an http request working is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare an app that is working with the server to the one that doesn't work.    Look at 1st request and make c# app \1st request look like working app.

Comment: Have a look, this one works fine: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6c9rizlyc7w1sv/App2_working.zip but when I tried to make the server work in the background like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qiqiwd9wu3ff11h/App2_notWorking.zip it doesn't work

Comment: You need to debug and specify which line the code is failing or hanging on.  I used Beyond Compare to see differences between two projects and it is not obvious what is happening.